# Sql code to get alphanumeric consecutive sequence order range

Tags: sql, sequential, alphanumeric

I need to get the sequential ranges in a sequence. if there is a break in the sequence i need it to reset.I have a set of alphanumeric ranges and need to see which are taken and which are available. The taken ones are the ones that have already been removed.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
    ([Value] varchar(4))

INSERT INTO #MyTable ([Value])
VALUES
    ('AAAA'),
('AAAB'),
('AAAC'),
('AAAD'),
('AAAE'),
('AAAF'),
('AAAG'),
('AAAH'),
('AAAI'),
('AAAJ'),
('AAAK'),
('AAAL'),
('AAAM'),
('AAAR'),
('AAAS'),
('AAAT'),
('AAAU'),
('AAAV'),
('AAAW'),
('AAAX'),
('AAAY'),
('AAAZ'),
('AAA0'),
('AAA6'),
('AAA7'),
('AAA8'),
('AAA9')
```

I am expecting to see the following result, as an example

```
AAAA - AAAM
AAAR - AAA0
AAA6 - AAA9
```

Comment: Is this a true representation of your data or just mock for illustration? Finding gaps in a naturally ordered sequence is straightforward, but something that has a specific internal order is tricky

Comment: Also, what dbms are you using?

Comment: ... also, what comes after ('AAA9')? Is it 'AABA' or 'AAB9' or something else?

Comment: it would follow the same order as the last column so it would be AABA to AAB9 with the last possible value being 9999. The Gaps represent the client numbers that have already been taken and removed. Basically we have client numbers that range from AAAA - 9999 and we need to see the available ranges. as some of the client numbers in that range are currently being used, which the gaps would represent.